# silverlight UnitTesting doesn't call TestInitialize

Tags: c#, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0

I use (or try) the Silverlight unittesting.

everything seems alright but the methods taged with attribute `[TestInitialize]` are not called before the `[TestMethod]`. Anyone knows a workaround ?

here is a sample where Method BeforeAnyTest is never called:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class TViewModel
    {
        protected MockRepository MockRepository { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// This is strangely not called automatically before any test
        /// </summary>
        [TestInitialize]
        protected void BeforeAnyTest()
        {
            MockRepository = new MockRepository();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TServerStartupViewModelCtor()
        {
            //BeforeAnyTest();

            var smsa = MockRepository.StrictMock<IServerManagementServiceAgent>();

            ServerStartupViewModel ssvm = new ServerStartupViewModel(smsa);
            Assert.IsNotNull(ssvm);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to define it as `public` instead of `protected`
ie:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void BeforeAnyTest()
{
    MockRepository = new MockRepository();
}
```